# Eclipse Galileo - Open file dialog path

Tags: eclipse, path, galileo

How do I get Eclipse to open files from the last directory I opened from, after re-starting Eclipse? It always reverts to my Windows profile directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That might be related to [Bug 292665 - File open dialog doesn't remember last opened folder](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=292665).

In which case this will be fixed in the upcoming Eclipse Helios 3.6 ([released in 6 days](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Helios/Simultaneous_Release_Plan))

Comment: Thanks, I've just started using Galileo but I will no doubt upgrade to Helios now as I think Eclipse is a good solution for PHP dev.